# Why did the sprite stop displaying in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I rebooted unity, and the sprite I put in stopped showing below:

[image]

Although all settings are the same, and the order in the layer is configured.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't disabling/changing the Sprite in code. Also set the Layer to be 100 just to make sure that it is really displayed before the background.

Comment: @MathewHD, there are not even any scripts on this gameobject

Comment: Even when creating a new object, you still can't see it.
Most likely this is a unity problem.